# jsTree 3 - How do I pre-check an item without selecting it

Tags: checkbox, jstree

I'm using jsTree 3 and trying to pre-check some lines based on a criteria.

Here's how I configure the tree:-

```
    $(function () {
        $("#ProductInterests").jstree
            ({
                "core" : { "themes" : { "icons" : false }},
                "plugins": ["themes", "html_data", "checkbox"]
            });

    });
```

I've then found three suggested solutions elsewhere on the net (the first half of the if should result in checked nodes and the second should result in unchecked ones):-

```
<ul>
    @foreach (var productGroup in ViewBag.ProductGroups)
    {
        <li class="jstree-open">@productGroup.Name
            <ul>
                @foreach (var product in productGroup.Products)
                {
                    if (Model.LeadProductInterests.Any(lpi => lpi.ProductID == product.ID))
                    { 
                        <li data-jstree='{"selected":true}'>@product.Name</li>
                        <li data-jstree='{"state":{"checked":true}}'>@product.Name</li>
                        <li class="jstree-checked">@product.Name</li>
                }
                    else
                    { 
                        <li data-jstree='{"selected":false}'>@product.Name</li> 
                        <li data-jstree='{"state":{"checked":false}}'>@product.Name</li>
                        <li>@product.Name</li>
                    }
                }
            </ul>
        </li>
    }
</ul>
```

Of the three approaches, the first results in the node being both selected and checked.  The second and third result in nodes that are neither selected nor checked.  I would like to get a node that is checked but not selected.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Get the latest code from the repo - this is a known bug which is now fixed. Also keep in mind that in order to have separate checked and selected collections you need to set `checkbox.tie_selection` to `false` (as seen in the fiddle below).

Once you get the latest copy (not 3.1.1, but the actual repo code: https://github.com/vakata/jstree/archive/master.zip) you can use this:

```
<li data-jstree='{"checked":true}'>@product.Name</li>
```

Here is the demo: http://jsfiddle.net/DGAF4/516/

Comment: Perfect.  I'd already downloaded the latest copy but didn't realise I needed to set the tie_selection option.  That fixed it.  (I'd vote this up but don't have the rep yet <sigh>)

Comment: edit> Oops, spoke to soon.  It's still not checking the box.  Updated code in original post

Comment: argh, can't update original post and putting the code in a comment makes it too long.

config now includes:-
checkbox : { tie_selection : false }

This is producing an unchecked box:-
<li data-jstree='{"checked":true}'>@product.Name</li>

Comment: If the fiddle I provided works, it should work in your code too. Make sure your config is like in the fiddle and that you have cleared the browser cache and that you are working with the latest copy of jstree. If it works you can simply accept the answer :)

Comment: Huzzah, tried it this morning and it just works.  Guess I was probably dealing with a dirty cache.  Thanks for all your help and congrats on a great piece of work.  Also, I finally spotted the Accept button :)